# Unable to save formulas under excel file when it is saved using openpyxl lib

Tags: python, openpyxl

Formulas in the excel sheet are getting removed when it is saved through an openpyxl python script.

Is there any way to save excel file without removing formulas using a python script

Expected: Formulas should not be removed and data should be read through openpyxl lib

Actual: Data is read, but formulas are getting removed

Comment: Could you show code how you read and save excel file?

Answer (score 0):

If you read file with `data_only = True` argument you read value from formula, but not formula.
From [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)

> *data_only* controls whether cells with formulae have either the formula (default) or the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Though xlswings, this issue is resolved

Answer (score -1):

I am able to successfully resolve this issue for my assignment.
First do not use `data_only` parameter. Only define the excel and the sheet using -
e.g.:

```
exl = openpyxl.load_workbook(exlFile)
sheet = exl["Sheet1"]
```

now again define the same excel this time using `data_only=true`

```
exl1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(exlFile, data_only=True)
sheet1 = exl1["Sheet1"]
```

Now while reading the data from excel, use `sheet1` while writing back to excel, use sheet.
Also while saving the workbook, use `exl.save(exlFile)` instead of `exl1.save(exlFile)`

With this I was able to retain all the formulas and also could update the required cells.
Let me know if this is sufficient or need more info.